# CPU sounds beep loud When It's start

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bios

When I start my PC, my computer plays a loud BEEP for 2 seconds and after that it starts abnormally like press F1 To Start.
I found some video in that many of the video tells to clean the RAM. After that I clean my RAM but it's not working.

So please tell how I get rid ofthis BEEP sound of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by conflicting **BIOS** settings or a **Bad CMOS** battery.

**Note:** If your time and date are not set correctly, your CMOS battery is more than likely bad. Try setting the correct time and date, save the settings and then reboot. If after turning off the computer the time and date get reset again, replace the CMOS battery.

Comment: I replaced the battery and save the settings it saved only for once and when i restart it will give me the same BEEP sound.

Comment: what is the model of your mother board?

Comment: Name : HP dx2480
Number : INA923015R

Answer (score 0):

Goto **BIOS settings** and **Disable Floppy Drive** and set HDD containing Windows to boot first. If it doesn't work try resetting the BIOS settings to default. On each boot BIOS detects some unusual things (like recently connected devices) so "Press F1..." error occurs.

Comment: Disable Floppy Drive means Can you Please Explain Step by Step ?

Comment: Goto your by pressing F2 or DEL key. In BOOT tab select the HDD and make it to the top selection. So whenever your PC boots it directly boot from your PC and it wont check the Floopy Drive

Comment: It's not working !! I tried this following steps it solves the problem of beep but only once:
BIOS settings -> Hardware Monitor Setup -> Reset Case Open Status (i make this enable) 

but when i  turn off and turn on the setting is change from enable state to disable state . so can you find solution of this .

Comment: It is Chassis Intrusion feature that doesn't bother the issue.  After you saved the BIOS settings reboot the PC and again goto the BIOS  settings and look the settigs are still there or changed. If the Settings are changed, you must change the CMOS battery

Comment: I changed The CMOS battery But It is Not Working Still setting of Reset Case Open Status s change from enable state to disable state.

Comment: Did you tried to disable Floopy Drive after CMOS battery change. 'Coz settings will be resetted once you removed the CMOS battery

Comment: If it also doesn't help then you should check the BIOS Jumper settings on the motherboard. You should swap the jumper to another set of pins

Comment: How i do jumper setting can you please tell me step by step ? or any link you have about jumper setting i have no idea about jumper setting.

Comment: Jumper will be near the CMOS battery. http://www.howtogeek.com/131623/how-to-clear-your-computers-cmos-to-reset-bios-settings/