# BIOS setting is not saved it's show me a default settings

Tags: bios

I change Some Setting Of My BIOS but After I Restart my CPU. it Will Show Me Default Setting of BIOS whatever changes i make it's not saved.so what is the problem in BIOS.What Should i do For Save my Settings ?

Comment: Replace  the CMOS battery?

Comment: I replaced the battery and save the settings it saved only for once and when i restart it will give me the same BEEP sound.

Comment: How many beeps? Are they short or long beeps? What is the make of your BIOS. What is the make and model of your PC?

Comment: it's a long and loud BEEP 

Name : HP compaq dx2480 
number :INA923015R

Comment: You have an Award BIOS. Here are the beep codes http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm. None of them match a single long beep :/

Comment: Please don't ask the **same** question multiple times. You already asked [CPU sounds beep loud When It's start](http://superuser.com/q/975224)

Comment: The questions are related, but one is about the cause of the beep and the other is about the BIOS not retaining settings.  They aren't duplicates but it seems likely that the two have a common cause.  It might be better to combine the two questions.  Describe both symptoms in one question (and just delete the other question).